# MySQL OR conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get records from a table that have a language column. If there is a row with a specific lang code (e.g. US ) i want those rows, but if there is not i need to get the rows with the wildcard lang code ("*") .

Is this doable in one query without filtering the results after the query?

I don't think it can be done, but any ideas that would retrieve data this way in one query would be appreciated.

Comment: Post table schema, and the query you have written so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic answer is pretty simple; wrap the various sections of the OR statements in brackets. And then take a good look as its one of the places people tend to make mistakes - always double check your brackets :)

```
where (column = 'US' 
   or (column = '*' 
       and not exists (select 'x' from table where column = 'US') ) )
```

Sorry - missed that requirement and have edited my answer to address it.  Now the brackets start to matter ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this will return both the US and the * rows ? I need just the US rows if they're there.

Answer (score 0):

If your database server is SQL Server 200X, Oracle or MySQL you can use the `union` operator alone which omits duplicate rows:

```
select a, b from table where column = 'US'
union 
select a, b from table where column = '*'
```

The `union` operator will take care of duplicates, where as `union all` will also return duplicates. Also I believe union has a much better performance in contrast to OR.

For further reading on this:

SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx

Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/queries004.htm

MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html

Comment: Assuming the values for a and b differ for different languages, this will return rows for US and *, which is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Try self join

```
SELECT a.*, b.field as field_original FROM `table` a
LEFT JOIN `table` b ON (a.id = b.id AND b.lang = '*')
WHERE a.lang = 'US'
```

and then in the application check if field is present, use field, else use field_original (also you can add case statement inside the select to always select only one of the values)

```
SELECT CASE a.field IS NULL THEN b.field ELSE a.field END
FROM `table` a
LEFT JOIN `table` b ON (a.id = b.id AND b.lang = '*')
WHERE a.lang = 'US'
```

(the queries are for example and are not tried)